# Mysql UNION ALL to count multiple columns BUT also insert date column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause, union-all

Hi Guys I have a question. I am still learning and am trying to get some date out. Beneath is the table. It has hundreds of lines, but for example:

| FormNR | Datum | XX1 | XX2 | XX3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2022-09-08 | 4 | 23 | 7 |
| 0002 | 2022-09-10 | 8 | 5 | 0 |

The table name is 'forms'. Now what I need to do is to count XX1+XX2+XX3 (for a year rapport).  Then I have a 'date from and to' selection box on my page. So the question would be:

What instanties have been used between a certain date in total but so that you can see a a total per Instantie (each number is a different instantie).

So for example...Between the 1st of January and the 1st of June a list of all XX numbers ( there are 36 ) with there total behind it

What I have is the following. Is works great and shows all XX's in a nice table but for the entire table, not per date. As soon as i want to add the 'between $date_from AND $date_to' it fails.

```
 <?php
            
  $sql_rg_total="SELECT forms.Datum, x.f1,Count(x.f1) 
             FROM
            (SELECT XX1 As F1 FROM forms
             UNION ALL
             SELECT XX2 As F1 FROM forms
             UNION ALL
             SELECT XX3 As F1 FROM forms) x
             WHERE x.f1 = '$subcat_id' 
             GROUP BY x.f1";
            
             $resultvv=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_rg_total);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultvv) > 0) {
                        while ($rowvv = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultvv)) {
                            $subnr = $rowvv['Count(x.f1)'];
                            
                            echo $subnr;
            
                            }
                    }
                        
?>
```

By the way $subcat_id is from another table which connects the number to a name.

I have tried to write it as clear as I could. I know it's a bit thought haha. Thanks anyway for any input. Really stuck.

Comment: re "As soon as i want to add the 'between $date_from AND $date_to' it fails." please show your select *with* the between condition added and explain how it fails then

Comment: "SELECT forms.Datum, x.f1,Count(x.f1) 
     FROM
    (SELECT XX1 As F1 FROM forms
     UNION ALL
     SELECT XX2 As F1 FROM forms
     UNION ALL
     SELECT XX3 As F1 FROM forms) x
     WHERE x.f1 = '$subcat_id' AND (forms.Datum BETWEEN 
                                 '$date_from' AND '$date_till')
     GROUP BY x.f1";


SORRY dont know how ro respond to your answer in well formatted way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(x.c) AS c
FROM (
    SELECT ((XX1 = '$subcat_id') + (XX2 = '$subcat_id') + (XX3 = '$subcat_id')) AS c
    FROM forms
    WHERE Datum BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'
) x
```

The value of a boolean condition is `1` when it's true, `0` when it's false. So `XX1 = '$subcat_id' + XX2 = '$subcat_id' + XX3 = '$subcat_id'` adds up the number of columns that match in a row, then `SUM(c)` totals them in the entire table.

You don't need `GROUP BY`, since it's the same column that you're filtering in the `WHERE` condition (and now in the `SELECT` expression). And this moves the date condition into the subquery.

Comment: thanks. i tried it. But still get:


Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Comment: I had a typo, `c1` should be `c`. But you need to learn how to debug that error. You should have error checking, and print `mysqli_error($conn)` when it fails.

Comment: Maybe because  'Datum' is not selected ? A again, I am new to these heavy queries

Comment: Why does Datum need to be selected? It's not being used, since you want a total for all dates. I just told you what the problem was, I had a typo.

Comment: I need a total for dates selected on the page. But maybe a stupid reaction from me. If c is now correct how should i then echo it out instead of the previous echo i used. Sorry trying to learn haha

Comment: `echo $row['c']`. You don't need a loop since there's just one row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248605/discussion-between-bas-schreuder-and-barmar).